# On swipe up or down , app start

Tags: android

how do i add **Swipe activity** in my app. So that If **i swipe on my android mobile screen my app starts automatically**
Can anyone suggest me??

Answer (score 0):

You might consider dealing with Widgets [Android Widgets](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html)

Comment: i don't know how to use these widgets

Comment: Try following the link I had given. It is a tutorial on Android Widgets.